# Is it a good idea to use a domain based e-mail accounts to register to financial services?

Tags: email, dns-domain

I normally use my personal email (e.g. @gmail or @yahoo) to create online financial accounts such as online wallets, bank accounts, stock market, and etc. I am currently planning to create an online wallet for my customers to deposit funds to when they make a purchase from  my online store--something like PayPal. Is it a good idea at all to use my domain email such as wallet@mydomain.com to register?

There are some things I can think of such as getting your domains stolen (through domain hijacking and other attacks) or your domains expiring by accident and someone snatching ownership of the domain--thus getting access to your financial information. But this is also true for personal e-mails. The only difference is that personal e-mails do not have an expiration so people cannot simply register your personal e-mail under their control and that people cannot change a gmail e-mail address to a yahoo e-mail address while domain names can be transferred to a different registrar and change ownwership.

I just feel it is not proper to be using my personal e-mail accounts when the business gets larger for instance. But i'm not sure what the typical practices are for business owners

Comment: Isn't the paypal.me domain specifically for this kind of stuff?

Comment: Locally people don't use paypal a lot. There are dozens of options but paypal is not popular here

Comment: Aren't gmail.com and yahoo.com domains, too? They are just domains controlled by someone else. You can't tell for sure how long they will be providing those services, despite it's not likely they would disappear over night.

Comment: Yeah technically that's true. More of having a business e-mail address rather that is based on your own domain. Not sure if there are any issues that i'll encounter or whether I should just stick with registering with my personal e-mail